# fe_sendauth: no password supplied in Composer

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to create a DAG in a new composer environment to test connection to a Postgres db. But I'm getting `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` error in Airflow. I'm able to connect to this db in our old composer environment using the same conn_id (without password).

```
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.models import DAG, configuration
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

dag_params = {
    'dag_id': 'test_postgres_yellow_connection',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'schedule_interval': None
}


with DAG(**dag_params) as dag:

    check_count =  PostgresOperator(
                     task_id="check_count",
                     postgres_conn_id='postgres_yellow',
                     sql="""
                            select count(1) from db_name.table_name;
                         """
                     )

    check_count
```

Here is the Airflow log:

```
[2020-02-17 06:01:17,142] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1403: Subtask check_count [2020-02-17 06:01:17,142] {postgres_operator.py:57} INFO - Executing: 
[2020-02-17 06:01:17,143] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1403: Subtask check_count                             select count(1) from db_name.table_name;
[2020-02-17 06:01:17,143] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1403: Subtask check_count                          
[2020-02-17 06:01:17,165] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1403: Subtask check_count [2020-02-17 06:01:17,165] {base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: id: postgres_yellow. Host: hotname, Port: xxx, Schema: schema_name, Login: xxxx, Password: None, extra: {}
[2020-02-17 06:01:17,217] {models.py:1846} ERROR - fe_sendauth: no password supplie

Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1714, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/postgres_operator.py", line 60, in execut
    self.hook.run(self.sql, self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 158, in ru
    with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.py", line 60, in get_con
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connec
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your old environment user's is set as a trustful user in your `pg_hba.conf` file. As you can see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) in the **trust** auth method:

> Allow the connection unconditionally. This method allows anyone that
>   can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any
>   PostgreSQL user they wish, without the need for a password or any
>   other authentication. See Section 19.3.1 for details.

Please let me know if it helps you